# AngularJs Directive for crossbrowser SELECT Dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dropdownbox

I'm trying to create below Cross-browser dropdown:

[image: Gyazo]

Currently this is my HTML:

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) { //temporory stuff

  $scope.investments = [{
    "name": "AARPOperatingFunds"
  }, {
    "name": "SomeBigTitle"
  }, {
    "name": "IhatezIE8"
  }, {
    "name": "ILoveFFDeveLoperEdition"
  }, {
    "name": "GiveMeSomeLove"
  }];
  
  $scope.investment = $scope.investments[0].name;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <span class="dropdown">
      <i ng-bind="investment" class="before"></i>
      <select ng-model="investment">
        <option ng-repeat="ip in investments | orderBy:'name' " ng-value="ip.name">{{ ip.name }}</option>
      </select>
    </span>

</div>
```

But what I need is, when someone selects the Dropdown, `ng-bind` will update and also

1. I do **not** want to **add mg-model** each time.
2. And main thing is if OPTION value is sometime like this "**AARPOperatingFunds**" it should get displayed as "**AARP Operating Funds**"

Please guide. Can we create any Directive here for the above purpose.

I need something like this:

```
<span class="dropdown">
  <i class="before" mySelectDirective></i>
  <select id="investProgram" ng-options="ip for ip in ips | orderBy:'ip' "></select>
</span>
```

OR this one:

```
<span class="dropdown mySelectDirective">
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-options combined with adding a "label" attribute to your array:

```
$scope.investments = [{
    "name": "AARPOperatingFunds",
    "label":"AARP Operating Funds"
 }, {
    "name": "SomeBigTitle",
    "label":"Some Big Title"
 }];
```

Then:

```
<select ng-model="investment" ng-options="opt.name as opt.label for opt in investments"></select>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: and How will I display label value inside <i> ?

Comment: also, orderBy name how do I add that ?